# Is the Koren Sacks Nusach Sefard truly nusach ha'Ari?

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, prayer-book, nusach-sefard, nusach-ari

[Koren came out with a KSS version in 'nusach Sefard.'](http://www.korenpub.com/EN/products/siddur/siddur/9789653013094)

Is this the nusach of ha'Ari? I'm not too familiar with nusach Sefard/nusach ha'Ari. I like Koren's layout and aesthetics, and I've used their nusach Chakhmei Maroko (Avoteinu) siddur and love it. I've used both sefardi and azkenazi siddurim (family is moroccan and lithuanian) and am interested in the Ari's concept of a 13th gate for people like me, but I want to make sure I'm using his nusach. If the Koren edition isn't the Ari's nusach, is his available anywhere?

Comment: Nusach Ari seems to me to have been "adopted" by Chabad. I am sure there are people who daven nusach Sepharad who do not agree that their nusach is not the real thing.

Comment: I doubt there ever was such a thing as "true _nusach S'farad_". What criteria would you accept as qualifying a _nusach_ for that title?

Comment: @msh210, I think I'm looking for whatever text is closest to ha'Ari's own nusach/kavanot. I suppose that the truest form would be a Sefardi/EhM siddur which could be traced back to Tzfat. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: @Izmargadi So if I found a 1600s siddur from Tzfat in the Spanish nusach, you'd consider that the closest thing to Isaac Luria's nusach? I think the best way to answer your underlying question is to study Lurianic Kabbalah with a teacher.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman - I agree. Unfortunately I'm in a smikha program at the moment which frowns on Kabbala as a whole. My proclivities have had to remain mostly on the down-low and have taught myself quite a bit. I'm mostly curious if other talmidei qabbala have any opinion on Koren's version of nusach Sefard and if anyone knows the source for that nusach that Koren is drawing on.

Comment: Izmargadi, since you've indicated in these comments that what you seek is _Arizal_'s own _nusach_, I'm editing the question to reflect that and to remove the request for a "true sefard", which is very ill-defined.

Comment: There are siddurim which at least intend to be as close as possible to the nusach of the Arizal, but in general Nusach Sefard and Nusach Ari (Chabad) siddurim are not that.  In fact, in the case of the latter, the Baal Hatanya explicitly combined a variety of nusachos to make one that he felt was best according to kabbalah, but which does not reflect the exact nusach used by the Arizal.  I might recommend offhand [Sidur Chemdas Yisroel](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=1&P_ID=3650) which at least comes very close.

Comment: [This siddur](http://www.seforimcenter.com/product.asp?numPageStartPosition=1&P_ID=1265) has the kavanos from the Arizal, but I don't think the *nusach* reflects the Arizal per se.  Ultimately I agree with @CharlesKoppelman that the way to "daven nusach Arizal" is to study Kabbalah with a qualified teacher.

Comment: The koren sfard siddur has been around for years (the original hebrew-only one)... the innovations are the font and the line breaks intended to bring out the meaning of the words. The nusah is the standard sfard which is the most popular nusah in Israel. The only changes are some grammatical and syntactical clean-ups--the editor was knowledgeable and careful about grammar. Also, the addition of zionist prayers, like an order of prayer for independence day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Koren Sacks Siddur is Nusach Sepharad, that is to say, the "Spanish-Portuguese" rite. Nusach Sefard is a variant similar to Ari which bears more similarity to Edot HaMizrach and Ashkenaz to Sepharad. The main differentiating point between Sepharad and Sefard is in Kabbalat Shabbat; in Sepharad, Bameh Madlikin is said, whereas in Sefard, and by extension other kabbalistic nuschaot, Kigavnah and Razah D'shabbat are said. In summation, Koren does not have a Sefard or Ari siddur, the only company that I know of who does is Kehot.

Comment: Current Israeli publishing practice is to label siddurim for descendants of those expelled from Spain, 'Edot Hamizrach', ע"מ for short. In contrast, anything labeled 'Sefard' is for the descendants of Eastern European Jews.

Comment: My perusal of the Sacks Siddur (Sepharad) has left me with an impression of it being closer to de Sola Pool than to Sefard (à l'Artscroll). Although admittedly this is a personal opinion, rather than one informed by research

Comment: ArtScroll carries siddurim in Nusach Sefard, ie, the Hasidic prayer rite.

Answer (score 1):

By using both the Nusaj Sepharadic (Edot Hamizrach) and the Yair Emmanuel version from Koren, I can tell that the second (Y.E.) is a Sfard (Ashkenaz) and not an E''H)

There are plenty of other differences in the Nusaj, for example the way Bircat Hamazon is said and the order of the Harajaman

There are others such as the ending of the Shabbat service when the final Shir Ha-Kavod is sung (again, the Y.E. edition includes it where the Sepharadic one does not)